# Fire dialog box when user clicks on external links

Tags: javascript, dom-events

There goal is to prevent users from redirect on accidental clicks on external links, when user fills up the form.

Problem: the whole code has to be abstract. I don't know which links user clicks, I don't know whether the form is fully or partly filled.
If the form is empty, then redirect user without dialog/confirmation box.

Here's code:

```
function exit_confirm(event) {
   let url;
   if (event.target.nodeName === "a") {
     url = event.target.getAttribute('href');
   }
   if (window.confirm('Do you want to leave the site?')) {
      window.location.href = url;
   }
}

function getAllElementsWithDataAttribute() {
  return document.querySelectorAll('*[data-]');
}

function registerOnClickChangeKeydownEventsOfElementsWith() {

 let elementsWithDataAttribute = getAllElementsWithDataAttribute();

 ['click', 'change', 'keydown'].forEach(evt => {     
     elementsWithDataAttribute.addEventListener(evt, exit_confirm, false);
 });
}
```

The code is not a final version. 
I have to get `url` from a clicked link and pass it to `window.location.href` 
I also need to check a clicked link if it is an external link.
`*[data-]` - here has to be smthing that defines the link

Comment: _“need to check a clicked link if it is an external link”_ - well then compare its origin (protocol, host name and port - or a subset of those, if you don’t deem them all to be relevant) to that of the current location. _“*[data-] - here has to be smthing that defines the link”_ - what for, why can you not simply bind the handler to _all_ links?

Comment: _why can you not simply bind the handler to all links?_ previously heard something like that as an advice, but didn't get much into this idea. Could you be more specific on this?  is there an example code?